# How to use lexical Tie in?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

Recently I came across a way to handle context dependent grammar using [Lexical Tie in](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Lexical-Tie_002dins.html)  but I could not find enough resource and examples on the same. I am aware of [start conditions](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/flex_11.html) in lex and that's not what I am looking for.

All that I found about lexical tie in is that we can declare a flag in the yacc file and based on the value of the flag context is determined. It mentions that code needs to be written in yylex to do the same which I am not aware of how. Can anyone provide resource and examples of how exactly lexical tie ins can be leveraged.

Also yylex function is auto generated by flex. What needs to be done to add some routine to the generated yylex.

Comment: It would be much easier to give an answer if you said what you are trying to do. In the example in the bison manual, the assumption is that code in lex actions will inspect the value of the global flag in the obvious way, which does not require any modification to the generated yylex.

Comment: I want lex to return differently based on yacc output. But I ran into a problem. I was setting the flag in one of yacc rules which will affect the next token. But before I can check the value of the flag in lex actions and modify returned token based on that flag;yacc look aheads the token and flex returns based on the previous value of flag. This is the problem I faced.

Comment: That is correct. In many cases, you need to set the flag one token before you need it to take effect, and that means the token immediately following the flag being set should not be affected by the state of the flag. If you can solve your problem with start conditions, that is often better.

Comment: But if you want a specific answer, please ask a specific question.